# How does rgba and hsla colors work with different colors.

Tags: html, css

I am reading the book: CSS Secrets: Better Solutions to Everyday Web Design Problems. And encountered this part where the color setting css can work for every potential background colors. The css is as follows:

```
.button {
    padding: .3em .8em;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    background: #58a linear-gradient(hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .2), transparent);
    border-radius: .2em;
    box-shadow: 0 .05em .25em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 0 -.05em .05em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    width: 2.5em;
}

.greenButton {
    background-color: #6b0;
}

.redButton {
    background-color: #c00;
}
```

The Jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/mr7kwxsm/. This does work. But I don't know how... How does the background color pass as a parameter to hsla and rgba color settings? They seem to be fixed values there. And since transparent is the last variable in linear-gradient. I am not sure how this is working. Can someone please help to explain a little bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are asking but I think you want to know how does your element get a color of `green` and `red` where you've defined another color using `hsla()` in gradient which is bluish with a gradient overlay.

So it goes like this. Your `.button` class holds a shorthand property of `background` where you specify a `linear-gradient` which is nothing but a `background-image` and you also specify a hex of `#58a`. If you split this shorthand you will read it like

```
.button {
  background-image: linear-gradient(hsla(0, 0%, 100%, .2), transparent);
  background-color: #58a;
}
```

Now further down you declare couple of more classes with their `background-color` so when you use `.button` and `.greenButton` on the same element, browser overrides the `background-color` of `.button` with `.greenButton` and that's how you get different colors using a common `.button` class and you override them by defining other classes.

```
.greenButton {
  background-color: #6b0; /* Overrides your #58a when you call 
                             this class with .button */
}
```

> Order in your CSS does matter. If you move the declaration
>   of `.greenButton` and `.redButton` above `.button`, your buttons will
>   always be of default color which is bluish.

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/mr7kwxsm/1/)

---

After you commented, you asked that why your borders adapt the colors, so the thing is that you use `rgba(0,0,0,.1)` for your `border` which is equivalent to a hex of `#000` with an `opacity` i.e `alpha` of `0.1`. Now since the your borders are opaque, you can see your `background-color` being rendered behind that.

Now I can explain you how borders work but I think it's not in the scope of this question.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I guess I am more interested in how the hsla and rgba definitions work in the .button definition. And how the color value is passed to things like border, box-shadow, and text-shadow?

Comment: Not really. The border color looks different in all three buttons. I know it is not very clear. But I adjusted the border into 5px and it is pretty clear they are of different colors then.

Comment: @LanceShi ok, got it, will explain

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I guess I understand how it works now!

Answer (score 0):

The class `.button` makes use of the property `background` to set various properties (colour and transparent gradient). In the classes for `.greenButton` and `.redButton` you only overwrite the `background-color` element. Therefore, all properties that are not part of the background-**color** element remain intact.